# Reset Security Questions

Tags: apple-id

I have forgotten my Apple ID's security questions. How do I reset them? I have tried searching the web, and could not find a way to reset it.

Comment: How would Apple be able to tell the difference between you looking for this information and someone trying to steal your id?

Answer (score 1):

In order to reset your security questions, you need to be able to log into your Apple ID first.

1. Go to [My Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com), as Apple calls it.
2. Hit "Manage your Apple ID" and sign in.
3. Go to Password and Security.
4. Click “Send reset security info email to [rescue email address].”

If you don't have a rescue address, or you can't sign in, [contact Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204169). From a quick Google search, they will ask you to generate a temporary support code if you can log in. If you have a credit card added to the account, they will ask you for verification.

*(**Note**: I haven't tried this myself. What Apple Support will ask you to do depends.)*

Comment: Could you explain the situation when one would be asked the security question? is it only in the cases when you do not know the AppleID ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 You may get the security questions when you haven't logged into your Apple ID for a while, or you are logging into your Apple ID from a new computer. Otherwise, it seems it asks you them at random times.